# Split/tokenize/scan a string being aware of quotation marks

Tags: java, string, quotation-marks

Is there a default/easy way in Java for split strings, but taking care of quotation marks or other symbols?

For example, given this text:

```
There's "a man" that live next door 'in my neighborhood', "and he gets me down..."
```

Obtain:

```
There's
a man
that
live
next
door
in my neighborhood
and he gets me down
```

Comment: Are there specific parsing rules you already have in mind? Current it appears that you want to split on spaces and commas, but keep single- and double-quoted text as a singular match. Are there nested quotes to worry about as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this works for your input:

```
    String text = "There's \"a man\" that live next door "
        + "'in my neighborhood', \"and he gets me down...\"";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "\"[^\"]*\"" +
        "|'[^']*'" +
        "|[A-Za-z']+"
    );
    String token;
    while ((token = sc.findInLine(pattern)) != null) {
        System.out.println("[" + token + "]");
    }
```

The above prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/LZXXX)):

```
[There's]
["a man"]
[that]
[live]
[next]
[door]
['in my neighborhood']
["and he gets me down..."]
```

It uses [`Scanner.findInLine`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findInLine%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29), where the regex pattern is one of:

```
"[^"]*"      # double quoted token
'[^']*'      # single quoted token
[A-Za-z']+   # everything else
```

No doubt this doesn't work 100% always; cases where quotes can be nested etc will be tricky.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  What about adding the ability to account for escaped double and single quotes?  For example: `There's "a \"man\"" who...`

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful based on your logic, you have differentiation between an apostrophe and single quotes, i.e. `There's` and `in my neighborhood`

You'd have to develop some kind of pairing logic if you wanted what you have above. I'm thinking regular expressions. Or some kind of two part parse.

Comment: Yes. I tried to put a simple edge case, where single quotes have two "meanings". I thought the logic wasn't  obviuos, and this is the reason why I asked for.